# oracle procedure to list table names and corresponding count

Tags: oracle

I am stucked with an issue.
I have a table called gd_table_order which contains tablenames.
And i need to get the table_name and count of each table to a target one.
target is a view.

[image: gd_table_order]

I only gave an example with 2 columns, there are 10 columns like this.So in the procedure we need to enter this as a parameter.

And there will be corresponsding 10 views to be generate. below is a sample of 2 views.

[image: V_CHECK_RECORDS_AUS]

[image: V_CHECK_RECORDS_BEL]

V_CHECK_RECORDS_* is the output view name

Could you please help?

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is exact requirement here, But you can use the following approach to fetch the number of records from each table.

```
SQL> -- This is sample data
SQL> WITH SAMPLE_DATA(TNAME) AS
  2  (SELECT 'CUSTOMERS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'INTERVAL_TAB' FROM DUAL)
  4  -- Your query starts from here
  5  SELECT TABLE_NAME,
  6         TO_NUMBER(
  7         EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
  8         DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' || U.TABLE_NAME)
  9         ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) COUNT
 10    FROM USER_TABLES U JOIN SAMPLE_DATA S ON S.TNAME = U.TABLE_NAME;

TABLE_NAME           COUNT
--------------- ----------
CUSTOMERS                1
INTERVAL_TAB             0

SQL>
```

**-- Update**

You can generate the view as follows :

**-- UPDATED THIS SECTION**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CHECK_RECORDS_AUS AS
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       TO_NUMBER(
           EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' 
                      || U.TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE oe_name=''BUL''')
               ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) NUM_ROWS
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS U JOIN GD_TABLE_ORDER S ON S.TABLE_NAME_AUS = U.TABLE_NAME 
 WHERE U.COLUMN_NAME = 'OE_NAME';
```

In the same way you can generate other views.

**-- Further Update**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CHECK_RECORDS_AUS AS
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       CASE WHEN U.COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN TO_NUMBER(
           EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' 
                      || U.TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE ' || U.COLUMN_NAME || '=''BUL''')
               ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) 
         ELSE 0 END NUM_ROWS
  FROM GD_TABLE_ORDER S LEFT JOIN USER_TAB_COLUMNS U 
  ON S.TABLE_NAME_AUS = U.TABLE_NAME AND U.COLUMN_NAME = 'OE_NAME';
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly i want. i can't fecth from user_tables. Also there are 100 plus  number of tables whiuch are stored in gd_tables_order, and corresponding 10 views needs to be generated. so table_name should be passed as parameters

Comment: Then your question is not clear to me at all. You should use some sample data instead of image and expected output with logic. as far as I can see from image, this is the solution that you required.

Comment: I uploaded an image with sample data in the question section.

Comment: This is awesome. i got exactly what i need.as we are takign count(*) this is taking some time to get the results from view

Comment: And i would like to add some conditions to this, i added..buit getting some error.ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing. and i can't post my latest query here. don't know :(

Comment: case when S.TABLE_NAME_BUL in ('GD_MSTR_FLAT_CLAIM_POL','GD_MSTR_ERROR') then
       TO_NUMBER(
           EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' || U.TABLE_NAME ||'where oe_name="BUL"')
               ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) 
               else
       TO_NUMBER(
           EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' || U.TABLE_NAME)
               ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) 
               end

Comment: There will be grey correct symbol at left side of the answer. You need to click on it to accept. It will turn into green.

Comment: ok, could you please also help to add this condition which i mentioned?

Comment: This will apply to all the tables right? i need specific tables to be excluded for this

Comment: Then apply where condition in main query.

Comment: I think you should ask new question and accept it as we are doing this in air.

Comment: i accepted this, its a coninutiy of the existing question.and there is an issue in the case statment that i need to know

Comment: can u pls help?