# ERROR during XML processing in Oracle query

Tags: oracle

This issue is linked to another issue which I posted yesterday
[oracle procedure to list table names and corresponding count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424008/oracle-procedure-to-list-table-names-and-corresponding-count)

I am getting an XML error while querying the below query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_CHECK_RECORDS_BUL AS
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       case 
       when S.TABLE_NAME_BUL in ('GD_MSTR_FLAT_CLAIM_POL','GD_MSTR_ERROR') then
       TO_NUMBER(
           EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' || U.TABLE_NAME ||'where oe_name="BUL"')
               ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) 
        else
       TO_NUMBER(
           EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE(
                   DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML('select count(*) c from ' || U.TABLE_NAME)
               ), '/ROWSET/ROW/C')) 
        end as
        NUM_ROWS
  FROM USER_TABLES U JOIN GD_TABLE_ORDER S ON S.TABLE_NAME_BUL = U.TABLE_NAME  order by S.order_id;
```

**ERROR:**

```
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 176
ORA-06512: at line 1
19202. 00000 -  "Error occurred in XML processing%s"
*Cause:    An error occurred when processing the XML function
*Action:   Check the given error message and fix the appropriate problem
```

This error is occured when I use case statement to add a condition, otherwise it is working fine.
The view will be created, but during the selction of the view, this error is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are missing a space in the inner query; but your quotes are also wrong; this:

```
U.TABLE_NAME ||'where oe_name="BUL"')
```

should be

```
U.TABLE_NAME ||' where oe_name=''BUL''')
----------------^
```

If you have a string literal that contains a single quote then you need to escape that with another single quote; two single quotes (`''`) are not the same as one double quote (`"`).

Also, `extractvalue` is deprecated. You can do the same thing with `xmlquery` instead:

```
TO_NUMBER(
  XMLQUERY(
    '/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(
      DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML(
        'select count(*) c from "' || U.TABLE_NAME || '" where oe_name=''BUL'''
      )
    )
    RETURNING CONTENT
  )
)
```

I tend to include double quotes around object names for this sort of thing just in case it ever has to deal with mixed-cased (quoted) identifiers.

So put together than becomes:

```
create or replace view v_check_records_bul as
select table_name,
       case 
       when s.table_name_bul in ('GD_MSTR_FLAT_CLAIM_POL','GD_MSTR_ERROR') then
         to_number(
           xmlquery(
             '/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
             passing xmltype(
               dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
                 'select count(*) c from "' || u.table_name || '" where oe_name=''BUL'''
               )
             )
             returning content
           )
         )
       else
         to_number(
           xmlquery(
             '/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
             passing xmltype(
               dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
                 'select count(*) c from "' || u.table_name || '"'
               )
             )
             returning content
           )
         )
       end as num_rows
from user_tables u
join gd_table_order s on s.table_name_bul = u.table_name;
```

I've left out the `order by` clause as that really belongs as part of queries against the view, not as part of the view definition - though you would have to include it as a column in the view if you wanted to be able to use it for ordering later.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54cb4fa2e1a687095aed335847dc6509)